# Add automatically a comment to flagged, uninformed questions

Tags: feature-request, flags, new-users

The experience to newbie users can still be improved.

Currently, a flagged question gets as comments just the stock flag text.  This text alone is not very accessible to people that are still "*uninformed*" (have no badge informed).

I propose adding a general sentence about reading [help] -> [Tour] before the actual flagging comment in any case where a flag is raised against a post from a newbie user.

Alternatively send a message to user, like:

> Your question got flagged and you are uninformed, so please read the tour.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what new users see when visiting just about every page on the site:

[image: Take the 2-minute tour]

[Here's what they see when they go to ask a question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice)

And, here's what they see when they go to ask a question after their *last* question [did... badly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow):

[image: Wait!]

I think we got this covered.